# Boot Options not showing in raspi-config

Tags: bootloader

I've been following this guide [on Tom's Hardware](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/boot-raspberry-pi-4-usb) to boot the RPi via USB SSD.

However, when I enter raspi-config, 3 Boot Options does not show.  What am I missing ?

- Raspberry Pi 4 Model B
- EEPROM version: VL805, Current: 000138a1, Latest: 000138a1
- Firmware version:

```
Sep  3 2020 13:11:43
version c305221a6d7e532693cc7ff57fddfc8649def167 (release)
timestamp 1599135103
update-time 0
capabilities 0x00000000
```

- Raspbian OS version

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

[image]

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the option has moved to another menu?

Comment: No such option. Maybe you should ask Tom.

Comment: Best to use the RPF documentation instead of a random website that's not being updated...https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md

Comment: Run `sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade -y; sudo reboot` then try again. There's been an update to raspi-config delivered this month.

Answer (score 1):

Menu items in this program are never fixed but I'm surprised in this case as the document is only two months old...

When setting up the Pi it is important to check what version of the raspi-config package you are using compared to the documentation.

Unfortunately, the 'about' menu option does not give a version number that you can check so you often have to hunt around to find it.  This is a commonality across all computer systems :-(

Even the Pi page may not help as even they do not keep the documents up to date all the time and issue a warning that:

> Note that the menu shown may differ slightly.

In my version, the menu commands are now found under option one (System Options) then option S5 (Boot / Autologin).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I had assumed that I had failed to do something correctly upstream rather than the options might have changed, so I didn't hunt around for them.  Much appreciated.

Comment: No troubles - if its OK, can I ask you to mark the question answered so it does not show up randomly for ever more but others can find it with a search.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find it under 6 Advanced Options ->
A7 Bootloader Version (Boot ROM Version in the old menu) &
A6 Boot Order (same in the old menu)

Comment: in `Linux raspberrypi4 5.4.83-v7l+ #1379 SMP Mon Dec 14 13:11:54 GMT 2020 armv7l` the boot options are indeed under  `Advanced Options`

Answer (score 0):

In the raspi-config menu of my just installed and updated Raspberry Pi (Model B) I found the boot settings in:

1 System Options
S5 Boot / Auto Login

with options:

B1 Console
B2 Console Autologin
B3 Desktop
B4 Desktop Autologin

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your raspbian version the Boot Options may be hidden in the System Options. So you'd have to access it likes this:

`1 System Options` -> `S5 Boot / Auto Login` -> Your Desired Option

Then close the raspi-config and reboot your raspberry.